# "Your data directory and your files are probably accessible from the Internet. The .htaccess file is not working." - Nextcloud

Tags: html, .htaccess, apache2, nextcloud

I recognized that my nextcloud installation has following problem:

“Your data directory and your files are probably accessible from the Internet. The .htaccess file is not working. We strongly suggest that you configure your web server in a way that the data directory is no longer accessible or you move the data directory outside the web server document root.”

My apache2 config of the directory with the nextcloud installation looks like this:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin emailadresse@email.org
    ServerName cloud.domain.yt
    ServerAlias cloud.domain.yt
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cloud.domain.yt
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/cloudflare/domain.yt.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cloudflare/domain.yt.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443> 
  ServerName cloud.domain.yt
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
 
<Directory /var/www/cloud.domain.yt/>
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    SetEnv HOME /var/www/cloud.domain.yt
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/cloud.domain.yt

    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess file (in the data directory looks like this:

```html
# Generated by Nextcloud on 2021-11-08 19:38:35
# Section for Apache 2.4 to 2.6
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_access_compat.c>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</IfModule>
 
# Section for Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  <IfModule !mod_access_compat.c>
    <IfModule mod_authz_host.c>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Deny from all
    </IfModule>
    Satisfy All
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
 
# Section for Apache 2.2 to 2.6
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>
```

It should work perfectly fine. But it doesnt. I also installed all required apache2 addons.
I also wrote with someone on a github post. The user said it would probably be better to ask on websites like this one.
Most other informations are already on the github post (about 9 hours old right now)
https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/6449

How can I fix this?

Comment: Since you know you are on Apache 2.4.48 then you only need a single `Require all denied` directive in `.htaccess`. Remove everything else, including the `<IfModule>` wrappers. But if you have access to the server config then why are you not using the server config (and disable `.htaccess` in the `data` directory)?